# как отображать и удалять не свои маркера?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-android

мне с базы firebase приходят маркера от разных пользователей, и через заданное количество времени они должны удалиться....но по факту получается, что из базы данных маркера(текущего пользователя) появляются и удаляются исправно, а с карты не удаляются у других пользователей (после перезапуска приложения они пропадают естественно)....

проверяю просто! беру 2 телефона и на одном ставлю маркер, он появляется на 2-ух телефонах, а удаляется только на том на котором установлен маркер, а на других нет(после перезапуска приложения на другом телефоне маркер пропадает естественно)

как это исправить, что бы он удалялся на всех устройствах одновременно?

делаю так:

```
// код для показа маркеров для других пользователей
    handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    DatabaseReference rootRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    DatabaseReference uidRef2 = rootRef2.child("Markers").child("Markers");
                    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
                                    String key = ds.getKey();
                                    Double latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                                    Double longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                                    Marker marker = hashMap.get(key);

                                    if (marker == null) {
                                        try {
                                                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img_4662878black)).draggable(false));
                                            }} catch (Exception e) {}
                                        hashMap.put(key, marker);
                                    } else {
                                        marker.setPosition(location);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    };
                    uidRef2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);

// код для показа/удаления маркеров у текущего пользователя
            DatabaseReference rootRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference uidRef1 = rootRef1.child("Markers").child("Markers").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            uidRef1.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Adding location for '" + key + "'");
                    Double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    Marker marker = hashMap.get(key);

                    if (marker == null) {
                        try {

                                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img_4662878black)).draggable(false));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        hashMap.put(key, marker);
                    } else {
                        marker.setPosition(location);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    String key1 = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location for '" + key1 + "' was updated.");

                    Double latitude = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double longitude = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    Marker marker34 = hashMap.get(key1);

                    if (marker34 == null) {
                        try {
                                marker34 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.img_4662878black)).draggable(false));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                        hashMap.put(key1, marker34);

                    } else {
                        marker34.setPosition(location);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location for '" + key + "' was removed.");

                    Marker marker = hashMap.get(key);
                    if (marker != null) {
                        marker.remove();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Priority for " + dataSnapshot.getKey() + " was changed.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "markerUpdateListener:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });

// код для удаления маркеров из firebase у текущего пользователя
            handler1 = new Handler();
            Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                    DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Markers").child("Markers").child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                for (DataSnapshot single : child.getChildren()) {
                                    try{
                                        long cutoff = new Date().getTime() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                                        Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(cutoff));

                                        DatabaseReference markerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Markers").child("Markers");
                                        markerRef.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).orderByChild("timeStamp").endAt(cutoff).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                                    data.getRef().removeValue();
                                                }}

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                throw databaseError.toException();
                                            }
                                        });

                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }}};
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Log.d("TAG1", databaseError.getMessage());
                        }
                    };
                    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
                    handler1.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }};
                handler1.postDelayed(r1, 1000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поскольку маркеры пользователей хранятся для каждого пользователя в отдельном узле, то для того, чтобы пользователь узнавал об удалениях маркеров других пользователей, он должен подписаться на события для детей для каждого узла, в котором хранятся маркеры пользователей.

Поясню на примере. Допустим у нас такая структура (я для простоты пропустил корневой узел):

```
{
  "Markers": {
    "user1": {
      "marker1.1": { ... данные маркера ... },
      "marker1.2": { ... данные маркера ... },
      "marker1.3": { ... данные маркера ... }
    },
    "user2": {
      "marker2.1": { ... данные маркера ... },
      "marker2.2": { ... данные маркера ... }
     },
    "user3": {
      "marker3.1": { ... данные маркера ... },
      "marker3.2": { ... данные маркера ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Для того чтобы `user1` узнавал об удалениях (да и других изменениях тоже) маркеров для пользователей `user2` и `user3` ему нужно подписаться на события изменения детей для узлов `/Markers/user2` и `/Markers/user3`. Лучше всего это делать когда такой узел для пользователя создается:

```
DatabaseReference allUsersRef = rootRef1.child("Markers").child("Markers");

allUsersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot userDataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    final String otherUserId = userDataSnapshot.getKey(); 
    userDataSnapshot.getRef().addChildEventListener(new new ChildEventListener {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(
          @NonNull DataSnapshot markerDataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        final String markerId = markerDataSnapshot.getKey();
        // это обработчик события, когда у пользователя с идентификатором
        // otherUserId добавился маркер с идентификатором markerId
        // тут можем добавить его в нашу коллекцию маркеров hashMap
        // аналогично тому как сейчас это делается
        ...
        hashMap.put(key, marker);
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final String markerId = markerDataSnapshot.getKey();
        // это обработчик события, когда у пользователя с идентификатором
        // otherUserId удалился маркер с идентификатором markerId
        // тут можем удалить его из нашей коллекции маркеров
        Marker marker = hashMap.get(markerId);
        if (marker != null) {
          marker.remove();
        }
      }

    });
  }

  // другие методы из ChildEventListener нужно определить тут
  // и они будут пустыми
);
```